# Git command explanations: push, pull, fork, merge

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-push, git-pull

I'm about to start a team project for a class with some people that already know how to use Git... I've never used it before and I'm struggling to understand the concepts behind how the whole process works.

Say someone on the team uploads some boilerplate code onto the repository. I'd want to `fork` it? And then work on it on my own and eventually `push` to the shared repository? What happens if two people work on the same file and there are some differences, how does that get resolved? And where does `pull` / `fetch` come in?

Sorry if my question isn't so clearcut... I just want to make sure I get the whole concept of how I'm suppsoed to use Git. Tutorials on GitHub and google queries have not been so helpful in giving me a good idea of how I'd want to use Git for a team project setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `git fork` command, maybe you'd want to `git clone`? For the rest of this answer, I'll assume that you meant `git clone` as that's the command that pulls down a local copy of a repo.

### General Workflow

What will generally happen is that someone will create a git repo on a server somewhere (either manually using `git init --bare` on a server somewhere or using github to manage it for you) that you'll all use as a central server. This is the **remote repo** and is called **origin** by default. If for some reason you lose the original repo you cloned from, you can always just copy up the /path/to/local/directory somewhere and then have everyone else clone from that. Your coworkers may have done this already, you'll have to ask them.

Once the remote repo has been set up, each developer can clone it. To clone a repo, create an empty directory somewhere sensible, install git and then run `git clone protocol://user@urltorepo.com /path/to/local/directory/` to pull a local copy of the repo down and stick it in /path/to/local/directory. After doing this, you will have a totally separate repo that mirrors the state of the repo at the time they cloned. You would then `git commit` changes you make, `git push` them up to the remote and then other people can `git pull` your changes down.

Once you've cloned, there's no hard and fast rule about how exactly you use git, as git is more of a set of tools and not something that dictates a certain workflow, so ask your coworkers how they use git. Most of the time however, every dev will pull the latest changes from the remote with `git pull`, make changes (often in a separate local branch), `git commit` them and then push those changes up using `git push`.

### Branching

Each dev can make local branches using `git branch foo`. This is fantansic as it allows you to keep master and your code separate until you explicitly want to merge them together. To create a branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b foo #This will create the foo branch and then change to it
# Do some work
git add .
git commit #This commits the changes you have made to foo
```

And to deploy a branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull #Make sure that you are up to date
git merge foo
# Fix merge conflicts and commit if merge says that you have conflicts
git push
```

Comment: :) I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

the procedure should be the below:

- pull the file
- edit it
- commit it(it commits to your local repository)
- pull it again (if there are any conflict you will Be notified) in that case you can solve it executing the below command(GitBash on your repository working folder):

  git mergetool

it will run the merging tool you got configured in your .gitconfig file

after that you can push your changes.

So, before you push your changes you need to pull the changes first so that you can resolve any conflicts occurred and then you can push your changes.

hope it clears your confusion!!

--Cheers!!!!

Comment: It's often more convenient to rebase instead of merge.